# SSRS Range Bar Display Data Labels Questions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

So I'm attempting to create the below mock-up for a work project.

[image: mock-up]

Within my SSRS Report I created a Range Bar with the Chart Series CustomAttributes set to "DrawSideBySide=False"

I understand how to show data labels, but ultimately what I would like to show the Start & End dates at each end of the bar segments. On top of this I am trying to figure out if it is possible to show additional dates that do not have their own bar segment. (Early Indicators, Today)

[image: ssrs sample]

I appreciate any feedback you might have on this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom label using an expression.  You'll need to show data labels.  Then click on the data label and input your expression, something like =(Min(Fields!StartDate.value) & " - " & Max(Fields!EndDate.value)).  The min/max should be scoped to your category group automatically, but you can add the scope if you want.